# How to convert a python array with float numbers to an array with binary values (0 & 1)

Tags: python, arrays, binary

How can I convert an array of floats to an array of binary numbers i.e. 0 and 1?

I'm predicting the values of a classification problem and a value 1 indicates toxic comment and a value 0 indicates non-toxic comment. My predicted test labels have come out as an array of float with e-0x where x ranges from 1 to 7. How do I convert the predicted labels to 0s and 1s ?

```
array([[9.8556435e-01, 3.3385050e-01, 9.6424425e-01, 5.6063890e-02,
        7.9712880e-01, 2.6943371e-01],
       [1.0463297e-03, 5.6922436e-06, 2.0974874e-04, 1.3053417e-05,
        1.3548136e-04, 4.4524670e-05],
       [1.5031695e-03, 9.3579292e-06, 2.6571751e-04, 3.0487776e-05,
        1.6680360e-04, 7.6472759e-05],
       ...,
       [2.4601817e-04, 6.2584877e-07, 5.6475401e-05, 1.6391277e-06,
        2.2351742e-05, 6.7055225e-06],
       [1.1185408e-03, 6.9439411e-06, 1.5538931e-04, 4.7504902e-05,
        1.0922551e-04, 3.1569600e-04],
       [9.7941959e-01, 7.9966664e-02, 9.3608207e-01, 8.6713731e-03,
        5.5538106e-01, 2.1400809e-02]], dtype=float32)
```

Actual result should be an array of 0s and 1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set this post array generation by setting a cutoff. I have set up a dummy example, where I get very small values

```
zeroes = (np.arange(1, 10, 2))/1000500
print(zeroes)
##
#[9.99500250e-07 2.99850075e-06 4.99750125e-06 6.99650175e-06
# 8.99550225e-06]

zeroes[zeroes >= 5e-6] = 1
zeroes[zeroes < 5e-6] = 0
print(zeroes)
# [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
```

In this instance, all array values less than 5e-6 are assigned 0 and all values = to or above are assigned 1. Assign your cutoff and apply the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You likely got probablities out. `9.8556435e-01` (also known as `0.98556435`) means that the classifier considers it to have 98.556435% probability of being toxic. `1.0463297e-03` (also known as `0.0010463297`) means only 0.10463297% probability of being toxic. You could set 50% as the breakpoint, and do it like this:

```
toxic = toxic_prob >= 0.5
```